# Is there any disadvantage in using PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE in Docker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

In many Docker tutorials based on Python (such as: [this one](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/)) they use the option [`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE) in order to make Python avoid to write .pyc files on the import of source modules (This is equivalent to specifying the -B option).

What are the risks and advantages of setting this option up?

Comment: to reduse the image size

Comment: Any drawbacks in terms of performance?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When you run a single python process in the container, which does not spawn other python processes itself during its lifetime, then there is no "risk" in doing that.

Storing byte code on disk is used to compile python into byte code just upon the first invocation of a program and its dependent libraries to save that step upon the following invocations. In a container the process runs just once, therefore setting this option makes sense.

Comment: So the take home message is that this option is useful and safe 99% of the time in the case of a Docker project. Right?

Comment: Like I said, it's fine if you are not spawning other python processes than the containerized process itself during the lifetime of the container.

Comment: @hek2mgl - how about using a docker container with gunicorn, which is spawning multiple processes. In that case, also the process runs just once?

Comment: @bartekch Every process would have to compile the byte code again. Depending on what you are doing this could be a performance issue or not. Probably it's just fine. I would say test it

Comment: What's the advantage?

Comment: The advantage of PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE is that .pyc files won't be written. The container's filesystem won't get modified at runtime and can therefore be read only.